# Is the big blind player allowed act if other players go all-in for at most the big blind amount?

Tags: rules, nlhe, all-in, blinds

Assuming the blinds in a NLHE cash game are $50/$100, three players are dealt in, and the players have these stack sizes before posting the blinds:

- UTG player: $100
- SB player: $100
- BB player: $200

After the SB player posts the small blind $50, and the BB player posts the big blind $100, let's assume these two example situations could happen:

1. UTG player folds, and SB player calls $50 for a total of $100 putting him all-in.
2. UTG player calls $100 putting him all-in, and SB player folds.

Is the BB player allowed/asked to act in those situations (is he asked to either check or fold) or does the dealer just go ahead and deal the board cards without allowing the BB player to fold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all players but one are all in or folded, the betting action is done. What would it even mean for the lone remaining player to "act"? He already has every penny of his opponents' money in the pot--he can't get any more.

In tournament play, when all players but one are all in, betting stops, all players still in the hand turn their hands face up, and the dealer deals out the rest of the hand to the river. In a cash game, it is not required for the players to turn their hands face up, but it is otherwise the same.

It occasionally happens that all players are all in for less than the big blind. In this case, the big blind player is immediately refunded whatever makes his bet equal to the highest opponent's bet, then the cards are dealt out.

Comment: When a player has the option to check in a postflop situation, he also has the option to fold (even though he shouldn't). That's why I thought that the BB player would also have the option to check or fold in those preflop situation examples. You wouldn't have a source for this rule? I couldn't find one in https://www.pokertda.com/view-poker-tda-rules/

Comment: In a live game, folding when you have the option to check is a fold out-of-turn, and a floorman can penalize you for it. In a tournament (check TDA rules #16), it is definitely not allowed, especially in this case. If the betting is over before the river, ALL hands must be turned face up--folding is NOT an option.